# How to get current visitor country timezone in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using `geoplugin`

```html
      function getusercountrycode()
      {
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $ch = curl_init();
      $curlConfig = array(
          CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp? 
      ip=".$ip,
          CURLOPT_POST           => true,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => false
      );
      curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      $json_a=json_decode($result,true);
      $countrycode = $json_a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
      return $countrycode;
      }
```

here i m getting current visitor country name but i don't no how can get visitor timezone

Please help me and share code.

if any help for my side. please reply me message

Comment: geoplugin_timezone get from here

Comment: $timezone= $json_a['geoplugin_timezone '];

Comment: Okay let me check and reply you @TechnoDeviser

Comment: Yes it's working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geoplugin_timezone get from here

$timezone= $json_a['geoplugin_timezone '];
```